# Open-source replacement firmware for an old feature phone (LG Cosmos 2)

Tags: open-source, phone, firmware

For several reasons, I still use a feature phone - specifically, the [LG Cosmos 2](http://www.lg.com/us/cell-phones/lg-VN251-cosmos-2).

Unfortunately, the interface is horrible.  I mean, really horrible.  If I receive a text message while in the middle of composing a text message, it interrupts me while I'm typing.  It doesn't know how to properly receive group text messages, and it imposes a severe limit to the number of text messages I can store, despite the fact that I have an extra SD card installed.

Is there alternative, open-source software that I can install/flash onto my phone?  I'd like to find a project analogous to [Rockbox](http://www.rockbox.org) for MP3 players.